# Lewis structure of ClO radical

Tags: molecular-structure, lewis-structure, formal-charge

The commonly shown structure of the ClO radical [described here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorine_monoxide) has a single bond between the chlorine and oxygen atoms. In that structure, chlorine has a formal charge of 1, and oxygen has a formal charge of -1.

Why doesn't ClO have a double bond between the chlorine and oxygen atoms instead? That way, the radical would exist on the chlorine atom, and both atoms would have a formal charge of 0.

Comment: Your premise is false. Similar question would make sense in case of, say, SO3, but not here.

Comment: @Mithoron why is that so?

Comment: Formal charges are introduced in **dative** bonds, not usual single bonds!

Comment: You can calculate a formal charge for any atom. It may not be the correct approach, but there is no rule about dative versus single bonds.

Comment: "Premise is false" is not helpful. The simplest reason would be related to electronegativity; it is larger for oxygen than chlorine.